# How to setup VPC subnets to connect MongoDB cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have an Elastic Beanstalk VPC setup with 4 subnets:

172.XX.0.0/24
172.XX.1.0/24
172.XX.2.0/24
172.XX.3.0/24

All are on different availability zones.

There is a node server running through Elastic Beanstalk with private IP 172.30.2.XXX
(I think this means they are in the same VPC area.

Node tries to connect with Mongo but gets the following error:

```
Connected to mongodb named XXXX at 172.XX.2.XXX
Express https server listening on port 8081 in development mode
{ [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.XX.2.XXX:27017]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 172.XX.2.XXX:27017' }
```

I have a MongoDB instance running on a cloudformation stack ((000F) Deploy MongoDB on AWS (Existing VPC).
RemoteAccessCIDR    0.0.0.0/24
Private IPs         172.XX.2.130.

I feel like I'm missing a permission step or something. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the security group rules for this instance 172.XX.2.XXX?

Comment: which instance the mongo or node?  mongo has 27107 open to 0.0.0.0/0 (but I think that means within the VPX and not externally) for both I/O

Comment: And what is this used for "RemoteAccessCIDR" can you explain?

Comment: not sure. I don't thin it's used

Comment: So the only reason I am seeing is your port not being open on 172.XX.2.XXX instance can you double check as per your question your Mongoldb is running on this instance 172.XX.2.XXX right? Also is this 172.XX.2.0/24 a private subnet or public subnet?

Comment: ok, now it is reading and writing, but I get this error:   
{ [MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false]
 name: 'MongoError',
 message: 'not master and slaveOk=false',
 '$err': 'not master and slaveOk=false',
 code: 13435 ]

Comment: but I only have one instance running... So where is the master?

Comment: You have to set "slave okay" mode to let the mongo shell know that you're allowing reads from a secondary. This is to protect you and your applications from performing eventually consistent reads by accident. You can do this in the shell with: rs.slaveOk() and then try